# $N$-fixed vectors in smooth representations are also fixed by ${\rm SL}_2(\mathbf{Q}_p)$.

Tags: matrices, group-theory, representation-theory, p-adic-number-theory, automorphic-forms

Let $N = \left(\begin{matrix} 1 & * \\ 0 & 1 \end{matrix}\right)$  be the upper triangular unipotent subgroup in ${\rm GL}_2(\mathbf{Q}_p)$ and $K_n = 1 + p^n M_2(\mathbf{Z}_p)$ the usual compact opens in ${\rm GL}_2(\mathbf{Q}_p)$.

I am trying to show that the subgroup generated by $N$ and $K_r$ would contain ${\rm SL}_2(\mathbf{Q}_p)$ for every $r \gg 0$. This would prove the claim in the title.

I believe that, I could make this work if I showed that the group $\langle N, K_r \rangle$ contains $K_{r-1} \cap N^t$ where $N^t$ is the lower triangular unipotent subgroup. I can't quite think of the right matrices from $N$ and $K_r$ to multiply to get the power of $p$ in the lower right hand corner to decrease...

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: Since $K_{n+1} \leq K_n$, if $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{Q}_p)$ is contained in $\langle N, K_r \rangle$ then it is contained in $\langle N,K_1 \rangle$, so I suppose what you are really asking for is to show this, no? I don't see why it would be helpful to consider $r >> 0$.

Comment: Hmm, isn't $\langle N, K_{r+1} \rangle \subset \langle N, K_r \rangle$ so knowing that $SL_2(\mathbf{Q}_p)$ is in the bigger group doesn't get you that it is in the smaller group? I want to show $SL_2(\mathbf{Q}_p)$ is in $\langle N, K_r\rangle$ for every $r$. [Sorry, will edit the question.]

Comment: With the edit it's understandable! (Replacing "some" by "every" did the trick).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a,x \in \mathbf{Q}_p$ with $x \neq 0$. A short computation shows
$$\left(\begin{matrix} 1 & -1/x \\ 0 &1 \end{matrix} \right) \left(\begin{matrix} 1 & 0 \\ x &1 \end{matrix} \right) \left(\begin{matrix} 1 & -1/x \\ 0 &1 \end{matrix} \right)=\left(\begin{matrix} 0 & -1/x \\ x & 0 \end{matrix} \right)$$ and
$$\left(\begin{matrix} 0 & -1/x \\ x &0  \end{matrix} \right) \left(\begin{matrix} 1 & a \\ 0 &1 \end{matrix} \right) \left(\begin{matrix} 0 & 1/x \\ -x & 0 \end{matrix} \right)=\left(\begin{matrix} 1 & 0 \\ -a x^2 &1 \end{matrix} \right).$$ Taking $x=p^n$ and letting $a$ range over $\mathbf{Q}_p$ shows that the subgroup generated by $N$ and $K_n$ contains both $N$ and the opposite unipotent subgroup, which together generate $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{Q}_p)$.

Comment: Ahhh! I am allowed N(Qp)! Thanks!! I swear I wrote down general equations but restricted everything to Zp. Thanks again---I have done this kind of computation before and I was frustrated I couldn't reproduce it! Thanks.